# listener for cell selection extjs grid

Tags: extjs, grid, click, save, listener

I have a grid which contains just one column. Each row essentially contains just a name. When I click on a particular name I populate a form on the right side of the column using that selected name.

Now what I wish to do is whenever a user selects ANOTHER name, whatever changes he has made in the components on the form on the right side for the last selected name, I wish to save them. All I need is a method to be able to just launch this saving function whenever he moves on to the next name.

The tricky thing is that the save should be done BEFORE I populate the components on the right side for this new selection. For populating I am using a `selectionchange` listener.

So in essence I want to be able to know my previous selection name and to be able to launch a save function and then populate the form with the current selection name.

Here's a flow for clarity:

```
let user select one name -> 
let user make changes on the form on right side -> 
let user select new name -> 

// I need help in the next step

launch save function for previously selected name -> 
populate the right hand side form using new/current selection.
```

Comment: Why not just keep the previous selection in a variable?

Comment: On the selection change I'm guessing you load the selected record in to the form. Why not before you do that, check if the form already has a record loaded (form.getRecord()) and when you have a reference to the currently loaded record, save() it?